# FileNotFoundError with matplotlib and tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, git-bash, gnu-parallel

I had been using `jupyter` and using some codes similar to [this tutorial](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html) for plotting contours using `Getdist`.
After that for some other things I have installed `GnuParallel` and `Git-Bash` and after that the plotting part of Python has been broken down.
I have two python version with 2.7 I can plot simple tasks but I cannot plot that tutorial. With python 3 I cannot plot anything.

I tried to reinstall tkinter but there is no straightforward way.
I have uninstalled all python packages, git-bash, gnuparallel and manually deleted all folders of them, but still after installing I have this problem.

any help please?

Full error trace:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 267, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2628, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1187, in draw
    renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1125, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 930, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 313, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 209, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 464, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 328, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 298, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 745, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 346, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2628, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1187, in draw
    renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1125, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 930, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 313, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 209, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 464, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 328, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 298, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: clearly, the code is looking for a file that doesn't exist. Does part of the omitted stacktrace show what file it is looking for?

Comment: @BryanOakley no, it mentioned files of Ipython, Matplotlib and tkinter

Comment: I think nobody will really be able to help you with the information given. Could you please post the full error trace and the part of the code that causes the error?

Comment: @ThomasKühn updated with full error mesage.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like some tool in your system is not installed or set up correctly. It almost looks like this is not directly python related. As the last `matplotlib` file in the error chain is `texmanager.py`, could you check what happens if you comment out the line `plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True` in the tutorial you are following?

Comment: @ThomasKühn you mean what should I do?

Comment: Could you try running the example codes without the line that I pointed out?

Comment: @ThomasKühn in that tutorial the most close line to youe mentioned one is `g.triangle_plot([samples, samples2], filled=True)` It is the operator for plotting the contours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189659/discussion-between-thomas-kuhn-and-ma-y).